# join a string vector in rust

Tags: string, join, vector, rust

I want to join a **string** vector into a `String`, but I got confused on the different result of vector of `&str` `&String` `String`:

```
let v1: Vec<String> = vec!["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()];
println!("{:?}", v1.join(",")); // OK

let v2: Vec<&str> = vec!["foo", "bar"];
println!("{:?}", v2.join(",")); // OK

let foo = "foo".to_string();
let bar = "bar".to_string();
let v3: Vec<&String> = vec![&foo, &bar];
println!("{:?}", v3.join(",")); // error
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `join` found for type `std::vec::Vec<&std::string::String>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:21
   |
11 | println!("{:?}", v3.join(",")); // error
   |                     ^^^^ method not found in `std::vec::Vec<&std::string::String>`
```

Any help and explanation is really welcome

Comment: There isn't much point having a `Vec<&String>`. A `Vec<&str>` is the same but more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, using a `&String` is discouraged: if you need an owned copy, use a `String` and if you need a reference, use an `&str`. Automatic dereferencing allows this to be reasonably transparent:

```
let foo: String = "foo".to_string();
let bar: String = "bar".to_string();
let v3: Vec<&str> = vec![&foo, &bar];
```

**Note:** In the above code, you don't really need to write the types explicitly, but I put them in to show that a `Vec<&str>` can be built transparently from references to variables of type `String`.

Comment: Thanks, Jmb. I know `&String` is discouraged, and I rarely use it. I really appreciate it   if you can help to explain it.